# Form input won't be marked as required

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms

I created a form with Contact Form 7 with the following HTML code:

```
<label for=".elementor-6 .elementor-element.elementor-element-5m0lukt .wpcf7 input[type="text"]"><input type=text textarea name="your-name" placeholder="שם מלא" required id:name </input></label> 
<label for= ".wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text.wpcf7-tel.wpcf7-validates-as-required.wpcf7-validates-as-tel* your-email"> <input type="tel" textarea name="your-phone" input placeholder="טלפון" id:phone required</input></label>
<label for= ".wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text.wpcf7-tel.wpcf7-validates-as-required.wpcf7-validates-as-email* your-email"> <input type="email" textarea name="your-email" input placeholder="אימייל" id:email required</input></label>
```

However, the required attribute is not working for some reason and the fields can be left blank. 
1) How can I make the fields actually required?
2) How can I add *field is required message next to the field once it's left blank?

Here's a link (there are two forms in this landing page): [mickeyberkowitz.com](http://mickeyberkowitz.com)
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Inputs are self closing so you dont put `</input>` you just use `/>` to close the tag so your code should be

```
<label for=".elementor-6 .elementor-element.elementor-element-5m0lukt .wpcf7 input[type="text"]"><input type=text textarea name="your-name" placeholder="שם מלא" required id:name /></label> 
<label for= ".wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text.wpcf7-tel.wpcf7-validates-as-required.wpcf7-validates-as-tel* your-email"> <input type="tel" textarea name="your-phone" input placeholder="טלפון" id:phone required /></label>
<label for= ".wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text.wpcf7-tel.wpcf7-validates-as-required.wpcf7-validates-as-email* your-email"> <input type="email" textarea name="your-email" input placeholder="אימייל" id:email required /></label>
```

Here is a fiddle [Fidde Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/jwyxxudm/)

Comment: So I changed it but it still won't be marked as required. I can send the form without filling out any fields.

Comment: Seems to be working for me I added a fiddle demo to the answer